# differential equations- area problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having some trouble with solving this problem.
Show there is one f(x) that its graph is in the first quadrant, and for every a>0 the area between the the graph above, x- axis down, y-axis left and x=a on the right is exactly $f(a)^3$.

I started by this; $\int_{0}^a f(x) dx=f(a)^3$ but I got stuck because I can't derive it since it is a number and not variable, so I don't know how to continue it. appreciate some help.

Comment: Very telling that this is tagged ordinary-differential-equations, but that you haven't considered differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

We will assume the regularity condition $f \in C^1([0, \infty)).$ Well, what you could do is define the function $F(x) := \int_0^x f(t) dt$ and you know that $F(x) = (f(x))^3$ for all $x > 0.$ Then you have that $F$ is differentiable and $F'(x) = f(x)$ (this is just the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus). It follows that $F'(x) = f(x) = 3 (f(x))^2 f'(x).$ You get the stationary solution $f(x) = 0.$ Otherwise, assuming $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x > 0,$ we get that $3 f(x) f'(x) = 1,$ i.e. $\frac32 ((f(x))^2)' = 1,$ so that $(f(x))^2 = \frac23 x + c,$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}.$ Note that you also have that $(f(0))^3 = \int_0^0 f(t) dt = 0$ (by continuity of $F,$ for example), so that $c = 0.$ It follows that $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{6 x} }{3},$ which is a solution to your equation. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. that was very helpful. I wasn't sure I can refer to a as variable and derive f(a) so I understand that I can. thank you!

Comment: Of course you can since $a$ is basically a positive dummy variable! Glad you find it helpful, you're most welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$\int_0^af(x)dx=(f(a))^3=\int_0^a3f^2(x)f'(x)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$f(a)=\frac{d}{da}\int_{0}^a f(x) dx=\frac{d}{da}(f(a))^3=3(f(a))^2f'(a).$$